# Prove $A$ is scalar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in M_n(F)$  and let's assume $A$ has only one eigenvalue. Also, $A$ is diagonalized.  Prove that $A$ is a scalar matrix.

**My Try:**
$${P^{ - 1}}AP = \left( {\matrix{
   \lambda  & {} & 0  \cr 
   {} &  \ddots  & {}  \cr 
   0 & {} & \lambda   \cr 
 } } \right) \Leftrightarrow AP = P\left( {\matrix{
   \lambda  & {} & 0  \cr 
   {} &  \ddots  & {}  \cr 
   0 & {} & \lambda   \cr 
 } } \right) \Leftrightarrow A({v_1}, \ldots {v_n}) = (\lambda {v_1}, \ldots ,\lambda {v_n}) \Leftrightarrow A{v_i} = \lambda {v_i} \Leftrightarrow A = \lambda I$$

Is that right? I'm not 100% sure of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: by the hypothesis $A$ is similar to $\lambda I_n$ i.e. there's $P\in\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb F)$ such that
$$A=P(\lambda I_n)P^{-1}=\lambda I_n$$

Comment: You're welcome!